# JPA Query methods specific column without Query

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I have DB Schema as

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `offers` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `detail` varchar(255) NOT NULL
 `status` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `restaurants` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `status` varchar(255) NOT NULL
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `rest_offer_map` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `rest_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `offer_id` int(11) NOT NULL
 `status` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

and entity as

**Restaurant**

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="id")
private long id;

@Column(name="name")
private String name;


@ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name="rest_offer_map",
           joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="rest_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
           inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="offer_id",referencedColumnName="id")}
            )
private List<Offers> offer;
```

**Offers**

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="id")
private long id;

@Column(name="detail")
private String detail;

@JsonIgnore
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="offer")
private List<Restaurants> restaurants;
```

Now I want to write JPA Repo function which fetches information about a particular restaurant(which is in this case is ONLY NAME but not restaurant). How do I get this using JPA function without writing any query, I have done that using this :

```
@Query(value = "select name from Restaurants where id = ?1")
public String findById1(long id);
```

But a) I dont want to use query in this.

Also lets say instead of only name there are other properties also like staff Count, rating etc. then how to get all without getting offers. I mean if I use **findOne**, then it is also getting offers and so it is running an extra query which is what I dont want and also without using @Query.(if possible).

P.S. - I am trying to avoid @Query because I think it will be performance overhead since JPA(Hibernate) needs extra effort to map it to entities at **Compile Time / Run-Time(Not sure)**

Comment: What makes you think there is no overhead without `@Query`?  If you simply write `select name from restaurant`, Hibernate is NOT going to constrruct a `Restaurant` entity for you

Comment: and, there will not be "extra query" for `Restaurant.offers`, as you have make it lazy fetched.

Answer (score 0):

You can use native queries with JPA.

@Query("select name from restaurants", nativeQuery = true)
public List findRestaurants();

You will have to map to objects.

Comment: Thanks but thats the Point. I do not want to use query, I was asking , is there a way I can do it without writing queries.

Comment: If you want to use Spring infrastructure, then no. Investigate different tools like [jdbi](http://jdbi.org) for example.